# PAGINATION AJAX LARAVEL [HELP]

Tags: ajax, laravel-5

My code:
This is my route:
    Route::get('demos/movies','HomeController@moviesReady');

In my controller i have this method:

```
 public function moviesReady(Request $request)
    { 
        $posts = Movie::where('m_visibility', 1)->with('generos')->get();
        return view('movieajax')->withPosts($posts);
    }
```

[In my movieajax view file i have this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V2GOj.png)

Here my 3 scripts:
[The scripts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQfNc.png)

AND HERE YOU CAN SEE WORKING THE CODED [VIDEO TEST](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F5rrlSDodrQ&feature=youtu.be)

Sorry but the CTRL+K send a error so i put in screenshots.

So if you see the video is work.
But i need to paginate all the movies when page load.
Because in the original web i have 500 Movies and is a lost of page content so i want to paginate.

I test some:
put render and in the movieajax use $post->links();
and work but the page refresh

-- SORRY IF SOMETHING IS BAD, i not perfect in english but i like to post in english to performance my lang.

If something is wrong sorry again, the CTRL+K get me some errors in the momento i post.

Answer (score 0):

IS CLOSED OR CLOSED I DONT KNOW BUT I SOLVED WHIT THIS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                $(".loadMore").click(function() {
                 alert("vamos a cargar mas");
                  $.get( "'.$posts->nextPageUrl().'", function( data ) {
                  $( "#displayMovies" ).html(data);  
                  });

          });
      });
```

### i use the normal pagination, just call back new data from the url